# History of short and tall sizes

Tags: starbucks, history, terminology

**Does the *short* and *tall* sizing come from Starbucks or did Starbucks adopt it?**

In my understanding *short* and *tall* are generic terms, but when I left Seattle (and in Seattle when I came back) it seemed there was a stigma against the terms because they were from Starbucks. Did Starbucks introduce these terms, and then other places in Seattle adopted it? Were the terms a part of Seattle coffee culture and Starbucks, as a part of that culture, used it too?

Maybe Seattle has nothing to do with it—I just know that in Seattle more non-Starbucks places use the same lexicon than elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The *Short*, *Tall*, and other sizing names are adopted by Starbucks to denote their own serving sizes. Any use in terms of coffee-serving sizes were coined initially by Starbucks which subsequently led to other coffee shops following suit as an established method.

The list of sizes are as follows:

- Short 8 fl. oz. / 240mL
- Tall 12 fl. oz. / 350mL
- Grande (*Big* in Italian) 16 fl. oz. / 470mL
- Venti (*Twenty* in Italian) 20 fl. oz. / 590mL for hot drink or 24 fl. oz. / 710mL for cold drink
- Trenta (*Thirty* in Italian) 30 fl. oz. / 920mL

As you can see these words are fairly generic but are used in this way as size-naming convention by Starbucks.

Costa also uses a different size-naming convention based off of Italian words.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? And when did Starbucks start using these terms? Thanks

Comment: Check out this post [here](https://customerservice.starbucks.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4722).

Comment: I don't think you read my question...